WSO2 Identity Server (wso2is-5.12.0-beta3) - Kubernetes Clustering Issues
I am testing the deployment of wso2is-5.12.0-beta3 in a Kubernetes cluster and I have added the below mentioned hazelcast configuration to the deployment.toml according to the documentation.
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/setup/deployment-guide/#!
I'm getting the below exception once the server starts up.
A direction to resolve this issue is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
[clustering]
membership_scheme = "kubernetes"
local_member_host = "$env{LOCAL_MEMBER_HOST}"
local_member_port = "4000"

[clustering.properties]
KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE = "<namespace>"
KUBERNETES_SERVICES = "<service>"

[] ERROR {Events.Framework} - FrameworkEvent ERROR java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize cluster

Caused by: org.apache.axis2.clustering.ClusteringFault: Invalid membership scheme 'kubernetes'. Supported schemes are multicast, wka & aws


There is a chance that the above error can happen if we have not configured the membership schema class path in the deployment.toml. Add the following configurations in your environment and do a restart
[clustering]
membership_scheme = "kubernetes"
local_member_host = "172.17.0.2"
local_member_port = "4000"

[clustering.properties]
membershipSchemeClassName = "org.wso2.carbon.membership.scheme.kubernetes.KubernetesMembershipScheme"
KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE = "<namespace>"
KUBERNETES_SERVICES = "<service>"
KUBERNETES_MASTER_SKIP_SSL_VERIFICATION = true
USE_DNS = false


https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/setup/deployment-guide/#clustering-related-configurations


Hi @athiththan thanks a lot.  After following the documented steps I get the following error.
ERROR {Events.Framework} - FrameworkEvent ERROR java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize cluster
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.clustering.ClusteringFault: Membership scheme class not found: org.wso2.carbon.membership.scheme.kubernetes.KubernetesMembershipScheme
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.membership.scheme.kubernetes.KubernetesMembershipScheme cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.core_4.7.0.beta2

I would recommend you to download and use the WSO2 IS 6.1.0, as it is a stable GA release.
